# Need help creating random divs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game, and i just need to make it so that every so often, a div (which will look like a baseball) will appear at a certain location. I don't know the problem, i know the if, else if statement works, but when i have it create divs, it won't work. Code below:

```
function createball() {
    rand = parseInt( Math.random() * 4);
    if (rand == 0 ) {    
        baseball = document.createElement("div")
        baseball.style.position="absolute";
        baseball.innerHTML = "<img src='baseball.png'  height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>";
        document.getElementById("field").appendChild(baseball);
        baseball.style.height = "30px";
        baseball.style.width = "30";
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
        setCPS(calculateCPS());
    } else if (rand ==1) {
        baseball = document.createElement("div")
        baseball.style.position="absolute";
        baseball.innerHTML = "<img src='baseball.png'  height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>";
        document.getElementById("field").appendChild(baseball);
        baseball.style.height = "30px";
        baseball.style.width = "30";
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
        setCPS(calculateCPS());
    } else if (rand == 2) {
        baseball = document.createElement("div")
        baseball.style.position="absolute";
        baseball.innerHTML = "<img src='baseball.png'  height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>";
        document.getElementById("field").appendChild(baseball);
        baseball.style.height = "30px";
        baseball.style.width = "30";
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
        setCPS(calculateCPS());
    } else if (rand == 3) {
        baseball = document.createElement("div")
        baseball.style.position="absolute";
        baseball.innerHTML = "<img src='baseball.png'  height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>";
        document.getElementById("field").appendChild(baseball);
        baseball.style.height = "30px";
        baseball.style.width = "30";
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
        setCPS(calculateCPS());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not put all the different configurations in an object, then just apply *config[rand]*?

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: as I was editing this code to improve readability, I couldn't help but notice that the code within all 4 conditions is identical.  Was this intentional?

Comment: the code is indentical just to see if it works, they will be very similar, the only difference is that their positions will be differnt

Answer (score 0):

when did you call this function?
since javascript is single-threaded, you have to release thread for rendering-thread have chance to draw it.

using

```
setTimeout(createball, 0);
```

to call your function might work.

another question, are you intentionally not removing old baseball?
and is baseball variable need to be global?

If not, using var to declare your variable is a better decision to avoid taint your global scope.

I've rewrite your code as follow, hope it work for you.

```
function createball() {
    var rand = parseInt( Math.random() * 4),
        baseball = document.createElement("div");
    baseball.style.position="absolute";
    baseball.innerHTML = "<img src='baseball.png'  height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\"/>";
    document.getElementById("field").appendChild(baseball);
    baseball.style.height = "30px";
    baseball.style.width = "30";

    if (rand == 0 ) {
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
    } else if (rand ==1) {
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
    } else if (rand == 2) {
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
    } else if (rand == 3) {
        baseball.style.top = "20";
        baseball.style.left = "20";
    }
    setCPS(calculateCPS());
}
```

Comment: i call it with a `setInterval(createball, 1000)` thanks for the code, its having the same problem i was, it is creating the divs, but they are all in the same place

Comment: also, the baseball will be removed if the user can catch them, so they will be removed eventually.

Comment: the problem that i am having now is that it is always creating the div in the top left corner, the position isn't varying (I changed the top and left values for each one)